# Flask web page cannot find image file

Tags: python, image, flask

On a Raspberry Pi, I have written a simple Flask app that displays the server's current date and time on a web page.  That part works great.
The page should also display an image. That part doesn't work. The image is stored in the photos folder under the app folder: Web_Test/photos.
I use a css file that is stored in a static folder, and that works great.
I use url_for to create the URL to the image:

```
<p><img src="{{url_for('photos', filename='image1.jpg')}}"></p>
```

Since photos is not a known endpoint for the url_for command, I used: `app.add_url_rule('/photos/<path:filename>', view_func=app.send_static_file)` to add the photos folder as an endpoint.
Every time I access the web page from a web browser, my command window, that I ran python (python3 photo.py) from, shows `GET /photos/image1/jpg HTTP/1.1" 404`.
There are no specific errors, but also no image.
I have read many of the posts on here about this issue, but nothing has helped.
This is my photo.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

app.add_url_rule('/photos/<path:filename>', endpoint='photos', view_func=app.send_static_file)
@app.route('/')
def photo():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    templateData = {
        'title' : 'Latest Photo',
        'time' : timeString
        }
    return render_template('photo1.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

This is my photo1.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style.css' />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Latest Photo</h1>
    <h2>Current date and time: {{time}}</h2>
    <p> <img src="{{url_for('photos', filename='image1.jpg')}}"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way your program is currently written, the image will be visible if you reorganize the project layout like this:

```
project
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── image1.jpg
└── templates
    └── photo1.html
```

The fact that you want to use `send_static_file` to display photos suggests that photos are static resources. If that's the case, then it would be better to:

1) Move `image1.jpg` to `static/photos/image1.jpg`

2) Change the template like this:

```
<p> <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='photos/image1.jpg')}}"></p>
```

3) Drop the `app.add_url_rule('/photos/<path:filename>', ...)` in `app.py`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried that but got the same problem. The command window shows this now:  "GET /static/photo/image1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: Well, duh.  Once I spelled the folder name correctly (photos instead of photo), it worked!  Thanks!  My only concern is that the image in the photos folder will be updated on a periodic basis.  Wasn't sure if that would be an issue with a "static" folder.

Answer (score 5):

I just created a folder named "**static**" in the project folder and moved my images to it and my problem got solved.

```
app.py
static
   |----image.jpg
templates
   |----index.html
```

and changed **index.html** file like this:

```
<img src="/static/image.jpg">
```